Elasticsearch Synthetic monitors healthcheck executed twice
I have an ELK cluster deployed on premise on Openshift 8.16.1.
I've also configured an Agent policy and deployed a fleetserver with 2 replicas.
Then I have configured my synthetic monitors with simple https pings.
The Synthetics monitors run every 2 minutes but in the history I see that I have 2 entries every 2 minutes and I guess is because the healthcheck runs on each fleet replica.
Is this expected?
I thought that the the helathcheck would have run in one of them.
How can I configure the policy or the monitor to run only in one replica of the fleet server?



Tldr;
Since you are on premise, you must be using private location right ?
Because from the documentation:

A Private Location should be set up against an agent policy that runs on a single Elastic Agent. The Elastic Agent must be enrolled in Fleet (Private Locations cannot be set up using standalone Elastic Agents). Do not run the same agent policy on multiple agents being used for Private Locations, as you may end up with duplicate or missing tests. Private Locations do not currently load balance tests across multiple Elastic Agents. See Scaling Private Locations for information on increasing the capacity within a Private Location.

